# jquery show() or hide() function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a website and using **MiniCart** in header.

I implemented the functionality like - show the product list on hover in and hide it when hover out - which is working fine.

But when I click on a remove button in the product list then the product list is hidden permanently and does not show again on hover.

This is how my code looks like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cart1,#header #cart .content").hover(function() {
    $("#header #cart .content").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#header12 ").hide();
    });
});
```

You can check my problem at this link http://gosokker.dk/

Comment: Question is not clear !!
Its working fine as i observed on the site .
Elaborate please

Comment: i think syntax is like this.. $("#header,#cart,.content").show();

Comment: I guess you should attach the event. Have a look for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Is this `$(".cart1,#header #cart .content")` ok? You have got `,` (comma separator) in your element identification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove item from your cart and cart becomes empty it loses display css property, check your javascript code which is executed on item removing, just make it set display:none instead of what are you doing.